# How to fake a big HDMI monitor?

Tags: hdmi

I have a desktop machine what I would like to access remotely, *but making all the 3D acceleration/framebuffering/etc* working correctly.

However, to "help" my video card to understand, that yes, there is a monitor there with a given resolution, I think something would be needed to talk him as if a real monitor would do - except that it wouldn't have a display.

(The display will be transmitted over the network with my protocols, maybe vnc/rdp/spectre, but it is another story.)

I imagine a small (& cheap) usb device, whose other end is the HDMI port of my video card, and provides this little cheat. But any similar solutions would be okay. What I want to, make the video card to think, that he is actually giving HDMI video signal to a real display (whose properties can be configured by me).

Comment: I suspect that you won't find such a device as wireless latency tends to degrade greatly in these types of scenarios being unable to yield the bandwidth and response time needed to take advantage of hw acceleration/etc. . "I imagine a small (& cheap) usb device, whose other end is the HDMI port of my video card, and provides this little cheat" <- this is basically the idea for a [chromecast](https://store.google.com/us/product/chromecast?hl=en-US), have you found this to be inadequate for your needs?

Comment: @BennettYeo Thanks, but I have a well-going gigabit LAN to this machine, this is why I don't need to really worry about the bandwidth. However, what I really want, is a hardware solution. I think, I can handle the software part. I only need something which provides a fake video identification over the HDMI. This question asks only for the hardware part. I've thought on already that I somehow buy a broken monitor with the same resolution and sub-pixel configuration.

Comment: I think at this point if you went the custom software route you would need to design your own module to receive data over Ethernet and output as HDMI and additionally, a computer side software/driver to to your custom Ethernet module. I don't know of any devices that would do this for you at the moment.

Comment: "Custom Software" -- You'd have to write code for it yourself from scratch. I don't know of any industrial standard that would do what you need.